# DynamoDB ignored in AWS Lambda Local

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB running locally:

`java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

and I'm trying to run `lambda-local` example:

`lambda-local -f aws -e event.json`

However, I don't get any output from dynamodb at all. **There is no error** and it looks like the call to `dynamodb.listTables()` **is skipped/ignored**. What's wrong?

My `aws.js` is as follows:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    accessKeyId: "BLAH",
    secretAccessKey: "BLAH"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("EVENT: ", event);

    event.int++;

    console.log("LIST TABLES:");
    dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err.code);
        } else {
            console.log("Table names are: ", data.TableNames);
        }
    });


    console.log("---SUCCEED:---");
    context.succeed(event);
};
```

and `event.json`:

```
{
    "obj"   : { "a" : "b" },
    "int"   : 1,
    "str"   : "qwerty",
    "arr"   : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
}
```

Output is:

```
EVENT:  { obj: { a: 'b' }, int: 1, str: 'qwerty', arr: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
LIST TABLES:
---SUCCEED:---
OUTPUT
--------------------------------
{
    "obj": {
        "a": "b"
    },
    "int": 2,
    "str": "qwerty",
    "arr": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

I'm expecting to see at least something between LIST TABLES and --SUCCEED:---
Yet there is no output and no error. I also checked DynamoDB log and there is nothing there. The line `event.int++` worked fine and I see all other `console.log()` calls.

Additionally, I run this code from node just to prove that the DynamoDB is working and it does list tables fine:

`node ListTables.js`

Content of ListTables.js (which is basically same code as above):

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  accessKeyId: "BLAH",
  secretAccessKey: "BLAH"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err.code);
  } else {
    console.log("Table names are: ", data.TableNames);
  }
});
```

Outputs as expected:
    Table names are:  [ 'Movies' ]

I created that table earlier just to prove that DynamoDB is actually running and accepting connections from `node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and solution is that the DynamoDB function is called asynchronous and therefore, the script finished earlier.

Once I moved `context.succeed(event);` line from the end to inside of `dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {` then I've got the output fine:

```
dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
console.log("INSIDE");
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err.code);
    } else {
        console.log("Table names are: ", data.TableNames);
    }
    context.succeed(event);
});
```

`lambda-local -f aws -e event.json`

OUTPUTS:

```
EVENT:  { obj: { a: 'b' }, int: 1, str: 'qwerty', arr: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
LIST TABLES:
---SUCCEED:---
INSIDE
Table names are:  [ 'Image', 'Movies' ]
OUTPUT
--------------------------------
...
```